# DefaultLabeller with Date as a prefix in cruise control .net

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am working on cruise control .net, i need a variable in ccnet.config that contains current date so i can use it in defaultlabeller that has prifix and postfix both tags. so i can refrence this variable inside my defaultlabeller block as a prefix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll" TaskName="MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Time" />
<MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Time Format="MM.dd.yyyy.HH.mm">
  <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="CurrentDate" />
</MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Time>
```

The result of this task will be placed in the property `CurrentDate`

This is a real life example:

https://github.com/jupaol/NCastor/blob/develop/Solutions/NCastor.AutoBuilder/NCastor.AutoBuilder.Runner/Targets/Labels/FormatLabelNameSufixWhenLabelExists.target

And you need to download the community tasks:

http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

Comment: Thanks but i need current date in ccnet.config file not on msbuild file.is there any way to access property of msbuild by ccnet.config file